# Are there any low-level functions for reading files in elisp?

Tags: files, generators

I am looking for something equivalent to this in Python

```
f = open('2021-11-10.org')
print(f.readline())
```

I know you can insert the file-contents into a buffer and do something like this, but that is not what I am interested in. I want a way to read a file one line at a time, without reading the whole file in at once.

I want to try making a generator like this (pseudocode):

```
(iter-defun open (fname)
  (let ((f (open fname)))
    (while (not (eof f))
      (iter-yield (read-line f)))
    (close f)))
```

Is there anything like this?

Comment: Ah - pythonic elisp :-)  I don't know of anything like this. [This](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CoRoutines) suggests that it is not easy. But maybe you can do the file/opening/reading/line-yielding with an external python program and just write the consumer in elisp.

Comment: The generator is easy to define, and a feature in elisp now (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Generators.html). It is the low level file stuff that seems to be missing. I thought of writing a module for this, but it seems a little too extra just for showing a generator!

Comment: Oh nice! TIL ...

Comment: Could you not just use a shell-script that does `read` from stdin, send it a character from emacs, and then have it `read` from your file (rinse and repeat)? And then just use `make-process`.